# Sending order to Forex or Stocks from Python strategy

Tags: equities, fx, quant-trading-strategies, python

I have my own strategy developed in Python. But I couldn't find a reliable method to send, close, and modify orders using Python. Are there any tools that help order management using Python?

I also would like to ask which brokers provide Python API? I cannot use Oanda as they don't support my country.

I mainly focused Forex, CFD and equities.

Answer (score 1):

We solve this task using this Python package: https://pypi.org/project/metaapi-cloud-sdk/ which is provided by MetaApi SaaS service https://metaapi.cloud.

The advantage of using this approach is that you can choose any MetaTrader-enabled broker for trading (there are plenty of these).

Answer (score 0):

The [Interactive Brokers API](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=5041) provides functionality for sending, modifying and closing orders for all of the asset classes you have mentioned.

It supports Python, as well as Java, C++ and C#. I cannot truly speak for the Python version as I have only used the C++ API which is barely usable with the way the current threading model "works"... however I can recommend [github.com/erdewit/ib_insync](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync) as it seems to simplify many aspects of the TWS and socket connectivity.

Seeing as you're in Turkey, according to IB's [Available Countries](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=7021) page, Turkey is supported!

Answer (score 0):

I second the use of the Interactive Brokers API. It is what I currently use to manage my orders. Here is a good blog to get started --> https://qoppac.blogspot.com/2017/03/interactive-brokers-native-python-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Great Python API is provided by FXCM. It is really intuitive and easy to use.

https://www.fxcm.com/uk/algorithmic-trading/forex-python/

Answer (score -1):

Quantopian uses Python. Or you need to convert to proprietary scripts like Think script

Comment: I believe they are only for Stocks market and they can reach to the source i think.